# Unable To Post HTML Form Data & Redirect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have an HTML Form that uses Google Sheets as a database, but I'm unable to get the form to redirect after posting the form data.

```css
.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.form-inline label {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

span.form-cta {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.form-inline input.email {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 20vw
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus,
input[type]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.67);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.13) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.53);
  outline: 0 none;
}

.form-inline input.button {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #ff7300;
  border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.form-inline input.button:hover {
  background-color: #dfe1e5;
  color: #475299;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .form-inline input {
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 80vw;
  }

  .form-inline {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}
```

```html
<form target="_blank" class="form-inline"
  action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/3/d/e/1FAIpQLSfU_zBaPh8gPdQ0b3EpGck-2mZP1FzVG6JP9SFTE3E4ul6hAw/formResponse"
  method="POST">
  <span class="form-cta">Get The Template</span><br>
  <input class="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="email"
         name="entry.2035384378">
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="window.location.href = '/thank-you.html';" value="Send it!" />
</form>
```

There are no scripts or functions (I have 0 experience with JS, JQuery, and Ajax).

I've been trying to get this working for 2+ weeks :,)

- I've read several posts on this, and the above info reflects my most recent edits after reading this post: [Redirecting to a page after submitting form in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221250/redirecting-to-a-page-after-submitting-form-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

"*onclick*" will not work because the button type is submit and after clicking on it, it will already redirects to the URL mentioned in action attribute of form.

Do not try to save the data via action attribute, instead use AJAX method in jQuery

Create button like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" id="saveForm" />
```

Here is jQuery ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $form = $('form'),
            url = '<action-url>'
        
        $('#saveForm').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $form.serializeObject()
          }).success(
            window.location.href = '/thank-you.html';
          );
        })
}
```

You can also refer this great reference:
https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

Since you have zero experience with JavaScript, use this reference to setup jQuery: [Jquery Setup](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_lib_google)
You can replace the code with above code

Answer (score 0):

If 'thank-you.html' file is in the same directory as that of the file having this code,
Replace -

```
<input type="submit" class="button" onclick="window.location.href = '/thank-you.html';" value="Send it!" />
```

with

```
<input type="submit" class="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'thank-you.html';" value="Send it!" />
```

"/" redirects to root directory. If 'thank-you.html' is one level up in the directory u need to use this line as -

```
<enter code here input type="submit" class="button" onclick="window.location.href = '../thank-you.html';" value="Send it!" />
```