# Form doesn't redirect to the submit message page when submitted and doesn't post to netlify

Tags: html, css, forms, html-helper

I was making a landing page, and this is my code, but when I submit the form, it doesn't redirect to the other page. I tried a lot of stuff but it simply won't work. I've tried using onclick, but it will still redirect you to the page if you didn't put in the required fields. Please help if you can.

form:

```
                <div class="column right">
                    <div class="text">Contact Us</div>
                    <form action="submitloader" name="contact" method="POST" data-netlify="true">
                        <div class="fields">
                            <div class="field name">
                                <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field email">
                                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
                          <label for="service">Choose a Service:</label>
                          <select name="service" required>
                            <option value="0">Select an option</option>
                            <option value="1">Bookkeeping</option>
                            <option value="2">Individual Tax</option>
                            <option value="3">Business Tax</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field textarea">
                            <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message.." required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button">
                            <button name="submit" type="submit">Send message</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Edit:** here's the css:

```
.about, .services, .skills, .teams, .contact, footer{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.about .about-content, 
.services .serv-content,
.skills .skills-content,
.contact .contact-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.contact .title::after{
    content: "get in touch";
}
.contact .contact-content .column{
    width: calc(50% - 30px);
}
.contact .contact-content .text{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact .contact-content .left p{
    text-align: justify;
}
.contact .contact-content .left .icons{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.contact .contact-content .row{
    display: flex;
    height: 65px;
    align-items: center;
}
.contact .contact-content .row .info{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.contact .contact-content .row i{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
.contact .contact-content .info .head{
    font-weight: 500;
}
.contact .contact-content .info .sub-title{
    color: #333;
}
.contact .right form .fields{
    display: flex;
}
.contact .right form .field,
.contact .right form .fields .field{
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.contact .right form .textarea{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
.contact .right form .name{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.contact .right form .email{
    margin-left: 10px;  
}
.contact .right form .field input,
.contact .right form .textarea textarea{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.contact .right form .field input:focus,
.contact .right form .textarea textarea:focus{
    border-color: #b3b3b3;
}
.contact .right form .textarea textarea{
    padding-top: 10px;
    resize: none;
}
.contact .right form .button{
    height: 47px;
    width: 170px;
}
.contact .right form .button button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.contact .right form .button button:hover{
    color: cornflowerblue;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't see in your code a redirect to another page when you submit (like with an script.js), so it's normal that there is no redirect, do you have an example that you were inspired by?

Comment: doesn't it redirect you to the page if you just do the form action?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting to a page after submitting form in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221250/redirecting-to-a-page-after-submitting-form-in-html)

Comment: Kinda, that post specifies that on click, they would be redirected, but they can do that without actually filling out all the required fields too.