# I want to redirect page on my wish location on submiiting the HTML form

Tags: html, css, forms, newsletter

I have an HTML form for submitting email id. Using `<form action""></form>` Which redirects to its action page but I want that on submitting the form either page gets refresh or redirect to some other page where I want but not on the action URL.

This is the code of my HTML form

```html
<form  action="#" method="post" target="_blank">
    <div class="card">
    <img alt="The Blogging Seed" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/revue/profiles/images/000/255/495/thumb/TBs_trans_favicon.png?1620927094" style="background-color: #f9fafb00; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 18px; height: 82px; vertical-align: middle;" />
    <h1>Subscribe to newsletter</h1>
       
<div class="signup">
  <form target="#">
    <input type="email" id="email-signup" placeholder="Enter your email here...." required name="entry.441329186">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" id="btn">
  </form>
</div>
  
  
</div>
</form>
```

**P.S: I did not want to remove my action page URL, as there only the data is being saved**

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Redirecting to a page after submitting form in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221250/redirecting-to-a-page-after-submitting-form-in-html)
 this answer might help you.

you can use onclick event and listeners on submit button.

```
<input onclick="window.location.href = 'https://yoururl.com/my-account';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />
```

Comment: Well do you mind if if solve your question using javascript ?

Comment: No absolutely not