# CSS button hover effects not working with id's

Tags: html, css

I do not have any inline styling. I am sorry for any inconvenience as I am a self-learner and this is my first question.

Many thanks for your support.

```css
#submit {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-width: medium;
}

#submit a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="email" id="email-label"></label><br>
  <input id="email" type="email" required name="Form-elements" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" /><br><br>
  <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/email-submit">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Started"></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please add the HTML you are working with? it will make it easier to diagnose your issue. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write a post that best enables the community to provide you with assistance. Please note that including a [mcve] will provide necessary context for your issue to be understood. Additionally, it is helpful to include the steps to reproduce the problem, the expected output/result, and the _actual_ output/result, and how they differ. Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. You have put an `<input>` inside of an anchor (`<a>`).  Please note that [interactive elements are *not* permitted children of the anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#properties).  You can imagine the issues if it were-- how would the browser determine which element you intended to interact with-- the anchor, or the button it contains?  If you want an anchor that looks like a button, you can simply use CSS to style it appropriately.  Malformed HTML can lead to strange, difficult to debug issues, so I suggest you resolve this.
2. Even with the malformed HTML, your styles are not written quite correctly to match as you have set here.  You have a `<a>` that contains an `<input>`, but the selector `#submit a:hover` reads as "target a hovered `<a>` that is *inside* of an element with id `#submit`".  So the rule is inverted from the actual case.  You could rewrite this a number of ways to make it match; here's one:

```css
#submit {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-width: medium;
}

a:hover #submit {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="email" id="email-label"></label><br>
  <input id="email" type="email" required name="Form-elements" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" /><br><br>
  <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/email-submit">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Started"></a>
```

...however, I would recommend that you don't go with this solution alone, but instead clean up your HTML and start from a solid foundation.

Comment: Tysm for your very detailed answer. "User Story #12: When I click the #submit element, the email is submitted to a static page (use this mock URL: https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit)." How would I make sure that my submit button takes me to another page without using it inside the anchor tag?

Comment: @React_ing - You are very welcome :) To some degree this depends on the technology being used.  But for a simple solution for a framework-free site [there is a SO post that addresses how you could accomplish this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44221250/6831341).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be it..

```css
#submit {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-width: medium;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.org/email-submit">
  <label for="email" id="email-label"></label><br>
  <input id="email" type="email" required name="Form-elements" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Started">
</form>
```

Comment: tysm for your solution :) many thanks for the support!

Comment: Maybe you're using firefox.. background-clip: text does not work properly on firefox.. -webkit-background-clip: text does work on chromium browsers though

Comment: [See this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23619197)