# (Rust, Actix Web) How to change method when using actix_web::web::Redirect::to(url)?

Tags: post, redirect, rust, get, actix-web

I am trying to handle a `POST` request to the `/upload` path. Once everything is done, I want to redirect to the main page. However, when I do that, it uses the `POST` method (as shown in the picture). Is there a way to redirect using the `GET` method?

[Redirect to main page uses POST method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJW0s.png)

Error Message:

```
POST http://0.0.0.0/                      [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 0ms]
```

```rust
#[post("/upload")]
async fn upload(req_body: String) -> impl Responder {
    // ...

    // This redirects to homepage but uses POST. Is there a way to redirect to GET http://0.0.0.0/? 
    actix_web::web::Redirect::to("http://0.0.0.0/")
}
```

I've tried using the methods in the [Redirect Crate](https://docs.rs/actix-web-lab/latest/actix_web_lab/web/struct.Redirect.html) but it still redirects with `POST`

I've tried implementing redirect directly from the `http form` from where I'm sending the `POST` request. [This is what I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221250/redirecting-to-a-page-after-submitting-form-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Redirects are "307 Temporary Redirect" [by default](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Redirect.html). Those keep the method for accessing the next page. You want "303 See Other" by using the [`see_other`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Redirect.html#method.see_other) method, which will convert all methods to `GET`.

```rs
actix_web::web::Redirect::to("http://0.0.0.0/").see_other()
```

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#temporary_redirections) from the `Redirect` documentation explains more.